# error(completionCondition 'All' does not evaluate to a boolean value) in completing one user task from parallel multi instance user task

Tags: activiti

I create a multi-instance user task and give loop cardinality as 5. It creates 5 parallel user task. But I want to complete only one of them user task, then it is showing:

```
org.activiti.engine.ActivitiIllegalArgumentException: completionCondition 'All' does not evaluate to a boolean value
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.MultiInstanceActivityBehavior.completionConditionSatisfied(MultiInstanceActivityBehavior.java:209)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.ParallelMultiInstanceBehavior.leave(ParallelMultiInstanceBehavior.java:125)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.AbstractBpmnActivityBehavior.leave(AbstractBpmnActivityBehavior.java:49)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.UserTaskActivityBehavior.signal(UserTaskActivityBehavior.java:147)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.MultiInstanceActivityBehavior.signal(MultiInstanceActivityBehavior.java:107)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.signal(ExecutionEntity.java:407)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.TaskEntity.complete(TaskEntity.java:201)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cmd.CompleteTaskCmd.execute(CompleteTaskCmd.java:50)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cmd.CompleteTaskCmd.execute(CompleteTaskCmd.java:24)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cmd.NeedsActiveTaskCmd.execute(NeedsActiveTaskCmd.java:59)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvoker.execute(CommandInvoker.java:24)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:31)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:35)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.TaskServiceImpl.complete(TaskServiceImpl.java:175)
    at main.MyFirstActiviti.main(MyFirstActiviti.java:67)
```

Comment: what's your completion condition?

Comment: It is running correct now, my completion condition was wrong.